# Why wont the MVC3 modelbinder parse List<List<int>> with empty List<int>'s in it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

I've got a type of `List<List<int>>` that I'm trying to get the modelbinder in MVC3 to parse and its failing.  My controller takes that type as a parameter and when I send fully populated lists like so, it works.

**Valid, properly parsed / bound data**

`[ [ 22, 12, 9 ], [1, 2, 3], [5] ]`

As soon as I send the same data structure to the controller, but this time with an empty array, it stops parsing the external collection.  Heres some data the binder chokes on:

**Valid, improperly parsed / bound data**

`[ [ 4, 5], [], [6, 7] ]`

That value is bound to a `List<List<int>>`, but it has a length of 1 and the first item is a `List<int>` of `4, 5`

So, how can I get the modelbinder to accept a `List<List<int>>` when some of the `List<int>`'s are empty lists?  I need the "valid, improperly parsed / bound" data shown above to work.

Whats worse is that there are no binding errors in the `ModelState`!

Also this is being sent as JSON to the controller (via `application/json`), if that matters.  I'd imagine if this is a bug, its likely specific to that json model binder.

Answer (score 0):

This must just be an implementation detail or an implementation bug in the model binder.  If you pass `null` instead of `[]` for your empty `List<int>`'s, it will work fine.

An odd detail of this workaround is that the `null` values are converted to empty `List<int>`'s!

If you send

`[ [ 4, 5], null, [6, 7] ]`

Then the items in your `List<List<int>>` will be:

```
 [0] = List<int> {4, 5}
 [1] = List<int> {}
 [2] = List<int> {6, 7}
```

I double checked, index `1` is definitely an empty list and you can access its Count, etc.

Also, the default Json serializer in MVC will serialize that list to

`[ [ 4, 5], [], [6, 7] ]`

instead of

`[ [ 4, 5], null, [6, 7] ]`

Fun.